# Debian Wheezy Linux Installing Packages Missing Dependency ( Potp 1.7 )

Tags: linux, installation, debian

I am a total linux noob. All I really know is apt-get ( to an extent) su , cd ,and dd and a few other minor things.

I am trying to install a disk encryption package. https://code.google.com/p/cryptsetup/wiki/Downloads?tm=2

I run `./configure` with the CD command set to where the decompressed package is located. The massive wall of text of checks appears and ends with this error code. `configure: error: You need popt 1.7 or newer to compile.` I'm having trouble finding out how to install/or get-configure-to-detect-potp.

I have ran `apt-get update` and `apt-get upgrade`.

General tips on linux also appreciated.

(I searched `potp` on Superuser and found nothing. Google didn't help much either. )

Comment: Just wanted to comment that, if you get a message like `configure: error: You need popt 1.7 or newer to compile.`, you can search for the package using `sudo aptitude search popt` - you will get a list of different packages, and then you will have to choose the one that fits your needs... in this case, `libpopt-dev`.  If you have doubts regarding the packages (if it is or not the one you are looking for), you can always do a `sudo aptitude show libpopt-dev` to get additional information on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

per the debian package documentation [here](https://packages.debian.org/wheezy/libpopt-dev), you need to install `libpopt-dev`

```
sudo apt-get install libpopt-dev
```